# How to set intervalstyle = iso_8601 and then run a select query in golang

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, pq

I have a table with an `interval` column, something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE validity (
  window INTERVAL NOT NULL
);
```

Assume the value stored is 'P3DT1H' which is in `iso_8601` format.
When I try to read the value, it comes in regular postgres format.

```
3 days 01:00:00
```

However I want the value in `iso_8601` format. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
so=# CREATE TABLE validity (
  w INTERVAL NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE
so=# insert into validity values ('3 days 01:00:00');
INSERT 0 1
```

you probably are [looking for](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-OUTPUT) `intervalstyle`

```
so=# set intervalstyle to iso_8601;
SET
so=# select w From validity;
   w
--------
 P3DT1H
(1 row)
```

surely [it can be set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) per transaction/session/role/db/cluster

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SET intervalstyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-OUTPUT) query and set the style to `iso_8601`. Then, when you output the results, they will be in ISO 8601 format.

```
_, err := s.db.Exec("SET intervalstyle='iso_8601'")
res, err := s.db.Query("select interval '1d1m'")
// res contains a row with P1DT1M
```

If you are looking for a way to change `intervalstyle` for all sessions on a server level, you can update it in your configuration file:

```
-- connect to your psql using whatever client, e.g. cli and run
SHOW config_file;
-- in my case: /usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf
```

Edit this file and add the following line:

```
intervalstyle = 'iso_8601'
```

In my case the file already had a commented out line with `intervalstyle`, and its value was `postgres`. You should change it and restart the service.

That way you won't have to change the style from golang each time you run a query.

Comment: isn't the SET intervalstyle='iso_8601' is per session ? so if i run 2 Exec, will it reflect in 2nd one ?

Comment: @ArjunKR, I updated my answer with a persistent way to achieve what you need.